# to transfer data from left node to right onConnection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

[to transfer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKCHl.png)

I want to transfer data from left node to right in same input box where edge is connected.
Can anybody help about it ?

Comment: Can you provide details what you have done so far ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.